# Proper way to override an Association in a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to override an association on a class instance.  Usually i want to return the association in ActiveRecord *unless* certain logic is met.
See below:

```rb
class Design < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to font

def font
  if override
    return another_font
  else
    # This results in a recursive call, stack level too deep.
    return send(:font)

    # This would work if font were an attribute, not an association
    return read_attribute(:font)
  end
end
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overridden methods can call `super` to call the original method:

```
def font
  if override
    another_font
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Or shorter:

```
def font
  override ? another_font : super
end
```